# Dimension of null space of a specific block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

I am analyzing the null space of a matrix $E$ given by

$E = \begin{bmatrix}AB \\ AC\end{bmatrix}$

where $E \in \mathrm{R}^{2m \times n}$, $A \in \mathrm{R}^{m \times n}$, $B\in \mathrm{R}^{n \times n}$, and $C\in \mathrm{R}^{n \times n}$.

Generally, we can say that the null space of B satisfies $\mathcal{N}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(AB)$ and $\mathcal{N}(C) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(AC)$.

(1) If $A$ is a full row rank matrix,

can we say that
$\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(B) = \mathrm{dim} \mathcal{N}(AB)$ and $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(C) = \mathrm{dim} \mathcal{N}(AC)$ ?

(2) Can we say that 
the null space of E always satisfies $\mathcal{N}(E) = \Big( \mathcal{N}(AB) \cap \mathcal{N}(AC) \Big)$ ? Does equality make sense?

(3) If $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(B) \leq \mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(C)$ and $A$ is a full row rank matrix,

can we say $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(E) \leq \mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(AB)$ ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried showing any of these? You should try and then ask about things you are having trouble with.

Comment: (1) take $A=[1\ 1]$ and $B=$ $2\times 2$ identity matrix, (2) use the definition of the null space, (3) use (2).

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the reply. I got that (1) is wrong, In general $\mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(AB) \geq \mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(B)$. (2) is true. (3) I am not sure. Even though $\mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(B) \leq \mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(C)$, we can not establish relationship between $\mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(AB)$ and $\mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{N}(AC)$. Hence (3) is in general not true. Moreover, $\mathcal{N}(AB)$ may not coincide with $\mathcal{N}(AC)$. Therefore, $\mathcal{N}(E)$ could be a zero vector.

Comment: Regardless $B$ and $C$, you know that $\mathcal{N}(E) =\mathcal{N}(AB) \cap \mathcal{N}(AC)\subset \mathcal{N}(AB)$. Since a nullspace is a vector space, it means that $\mathcal{N}(E)$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{N}(AB)$. What can you say about the dimentions?

Comment: @A.Γ. I think you are right. $\mathcal{N}(E) \subset \mathcal{N}(AB)$. This implies  $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(E) \leq \mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(AB)$. Am I right when I say I can not establish relationship between $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(AB) $ and $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(AC) $ given $\mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(B) \leq \mathrm{dim}\  \mathcal{N}(C)$ ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. Take again $A$ as a row nonzero vector. It may be $AB=0$, $AC\ne 0$ and, vice versa, $AB\ne 0$, $AC=0$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the reply and the help.